# User match functionality not working on select posts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

While I have experienced this periodically, have decided to report it today. Comment [How does °, ± & ² produce ░, ▒ & ▓ in this batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665821/how-does-produce-in-this-batch-file/13668495#comment18799438_13668495) didn't match kamilk's name, and actually removed the @kamilk if it was starting the post completely. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments always notify the original author of the post (which is who you were trying to notify) regardless of whether or not you `@name` them. Therefore, if the owner of the post is the only other person talking in the comments, the leading `@name` will be removed since it is redundant. So, basically, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

From [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

> The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment. There is no need to use @name to notify them. (You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the author have been commenting on the post so far, the @name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.)

Comment: Thanks for the citation eldarerathis. I have asked quite a few meta questions today, and it would have been good for several of them to more actively notify users of their existence, through mechanisms (Pop up, click to dismiss boxes would seem most appropriate here) that are also very well utilized in other areas of the site.